# Unable to start MongoDB using mongod

Tags: mongodb

I am unable to start mongodb , below image depicts the issue am facing.

[image]

Any idea what the issue could be.

Comment: Show us the full configuration file contents. And while you're at it please replace the screenshot with just the "text" output. That stuff in the console is called "text" by the way.

Comment: by "full configuration file contents" , you mean contents of C:\data\db folder ?

Comment: No I mean `mongod.cfg` or `mongod.yml` or whatever your executable's `--config` option is set to read.

Comment: I have installed Mongodb again , now its fine